# Can I capture a zoomed-in screen with the "Screen Capture" feature of OS X?

Tags: macos, screen-capture, zoom

Sometimes I use the Accessibility -- Zoom gesture to zoom in on one part of my screen by holding down the CTRL key. But if I do a Screen Capture (using Command (⌘) + Shift + 3), the point-of-view of the image produced is the standard full screen, not the zoomed-in area that I was actually looking at when I pressed the keys.

Command (⌘) + Shift + 4 does not work either.

Is there a way to way to capture my zoomed-in screen?

(2013 rMBP) -- (OS X 10.11.3)

Comment: Why not taking normal screenshot (CMD+SHIFT+4) and then resize the image in **Preview.app** in `Tools` -> `Adjust Size...` ?

Comment: Good tip; manually changing the resolution achieves the same effect. But 1) It takes longer/is less convenient and 2) The resulting resampled image is lower quality than the equivalent zoomed-in screen view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because the capture is capturing the pixels that comprise the selected area, not the 'screen' as it is displayed to you.

It's something I've wished for in the past, too.